# Calling classes through applet

Tags: java, executable-jar, japplet

Hello I am newbie to Applets and i need help in understanding something.

So I created an applet in eclipse that calls another class file and its methods when the button on the applet is clicked.

```
public class mainApplet extends JApplet {
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;

private int x;
private int y;
private int result;
public mainApplet() {

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setColumns(10);
    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");
    final JCheckBox ChckbxADD= new JCheckBox("Add");
    final JCheckBox chckbxLaunch = new JCheckBox("Launch  Browser");

    GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(49)
                        .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(26)
                        .addComponent(textField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(89)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(btnCalculate)
                            .addComponent(textField_2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(ChckbxADD)
                                .addComponent(chckbxLaunch)))))
                .addContainerGap(203, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(48)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18)
                .addComponent(ChckbxADD)
                .addGap(3)
                .addComponent(chckbxLaunch)
                .addGap(20)
                .addComponent(btnCalculate)
                .addGap(28)
                .addComponent(textField_2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(74, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);


    btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Functions func = new Functions();


            if (ChckbxADD.isSelected()){
                x=Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                y=Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
                result=func.addition(x, y);
                textField_2.setText(String.valueOf(result));

            }
            if(chckbxLaunch.isSelected()){
                func.Launch();

            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

This works when I run it through eclipse. I exported the class files along with the applet file in a jar (Calc.jar). Then, I used the following simple html to call the applet. This html is a local file.

```
   <HTML>
     <HEAD>
        </HEAD>
     <BODY>
     <div >
     <APPLET CODE="mainApplet.class" archive="Calc.jar" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="500">
     </APPLET>
     </div>
    </BODY>
     </HTML>
```

The applet is in MainApplet class and it calls on a Functions class.

```
   public class Functions {

        public void Launch(){

WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");


}

public int addition(int x, int y){

    int result;
    result=x + y;
    return result;

}
```

}

When the applet is launched in the browser and the "Launch Browser" checkbox is checked and the button is clicked, a firefox window should open and launch google.com.  In eclipse, this happens perfectly. But when the applet is embedded in the local site, nothing happens when the "Launch Browser" checkbox is checked and the button is clicked. I have another function that is used on applet ( addition), and that works as designed. The user can input two number in two Jtextfields and the checkbox for "add" is checked and when the button is clicked, the result is displayed on another jtextfield on the applet. This works fine but the other function doesnt work.

UPDATE:

The following is the exception in the console:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    at mainApplet$1.actionPerformed(mainApplet.java:75)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 36 more
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The applet element is completely invalid.  What is your question?

Comment: My question: how can I use the other classes that are within the jar. The applet uses a class by calling it when the button is clicked. However, when i embedded the applet within a webpage, the applet showed up but nothing happens when i click the button.

Comment: What is the output seen in the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml)?  What is the (new, validated) HTML?  What is the name of the Jar containing the classes that must be called on button click?  What is the link to the web page?

Comment: I think My problem is that I am using external jars that are being used in the applet. However I am not calling them correctly through my HTML.

Comment: *"I think.."*  Good luck with that. You are not answering my questions so I can be of no further help.  I don't know why you bothered to ask other people in the first place.

Comment: I had answered your questions by updating my post. Not sure if you saw that. When I exported the jar file, I had made sure all of the resources were in the jar. I didnt know that I have to specifically call the selenium jars in my HTML again. I am not sure how to call the selenium webdriver jars in my HTML. Sry if I sound like complete newbie but I am just trying to learn. So if you dont want to help, you dont need to. Thanks

Comment: OK - did not notice the edit.  What is reported in the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) when run in a web page?  I expect it will show something related to security - e.g. an `AccessControlException`.

Comment: Hey Thanks for responding again..I get the following error in the console:  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
 at mainApplet$1.actionPerformed(mainApplet.java:75)

Comment: I have added the console output in the post right now.

Comment: Change `archive="Calc.jar"` to `archive="Calc.jar,x.jar"` where `x.jar` is the name of the Jar containing the `WebDriver` class.

Comment: Hey thanks! That worked. Only works with IE though. Firefox throws ExceptionInInitializerError FirefoxBinary error but that is no biggie. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> > What is reported in the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) when run in a web page? I expect it will show something related to security - e.g. an `AccessControlException`.
>
> I get the following error in the console:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
```

Change:

```
archive="Calc.jar"
```

to:

```
archive="Calc.jar,x.jar"
```

..where `x.jar` is the name of the Jar containing the `WebDriver` class.